# Calling multiple SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to work asynchronously on one database table and commit changes to it but it doesn't work as I would like it to.

This is my first method where I'm running a task on object constructor which is non-busy waiting for some new objects in the collection and processing them one by one. **(Deleting from the table)**

```
    private static BlockingCollection<QueuedLog> queue = new BlockingCollection<QueuedLog>();

    private void Start()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (taskQueueActive)
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    QueuedLog log = queueLogs.Take();

                    // I process it somehow here

                    uow.QueuedLogRepository.Delete(log);

                    if (queueLogs.Count == 0)
                        uow.Save();

                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And here's the second method which is providing the objects to the database. **(Adding to the table)**

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            uow.MonitoringIdRepository.Add(logs.First(), out id);
            uow.QueuedLogRepository.Add(logs, id);
            uow.Save();

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Both methods are using the same **UnitOfWork** object with needed repositories.

After I run the app and while the queue task is running - when I'm sending new objects to the second method, I'm getting the error below:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

The question is: how to get rid of this exception? Or how can I do it in some other way? I've tried already the new EF 6.0 BeginTransaction method but it also didn't work for me (or maybe i used them wrong).

Comment: Any reaons you aren't using the native Async calls?

Comment: Are you using the same data context on multiple threads?

Comment: Actually... Yes, I'm using the same context on multiple threads. Is this the reason why I'm getting all those errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be sharing your context objects across multiple threads.  The error message you posted is essentially stating that the context object realizes entities have been modified.

Try using a separate context object for each thread: [Entity Framework Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455634/entity-framework-thead-safety)

Comment: So what should I do? When I will create context for both threads and still process ADD/DELETE actions but on separate contexts, will it work? Lets say this is a rhetorical question - I'll check this out when I'll come back home. Thanks a lot!