# Does a static class reuse Entity Framework connection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does this static class reuse Entity Framework connection and is it thread safe?

```
public static class TeamService
{
    public static Team GetTeam(string id)
    {
        using (var Db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            //TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the context manages connections to the database. The context opens and closes connections as needed. For example, the context opens a connection to execute a query, and then closes the connection when all the result sets have been processed.

-- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737

> A separate instance of context for each thread is thread-safe. As long
>   as each thread of execution has its own instance of EF context you
>   will be fine.

-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455827

Comment: Note that there is a distinct difference between a *connection* and a *context*. Having a context per call doesn't necessarily mean there is a *connection* per call.

Comment: Thanks for point out my mistake.