# Task.Factory how to create new DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, task

I have a case where I want to put EF inserts inside Task and return results without making user to wait like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   InsertToDatabase(data);
});
```

But for this I must create new `DbContext` because other one will be disposed of course so I need to initialize repositories again. I am using constructor injection but in this case I can't resolve this dependency. How I should create my repositories inside Task.Factory?

Comment: Just create a new context and use `await` with async versions of EF rather than calling `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. The latter is a poor use of async mechanisms for your example.

Comment: but await will wait until inserts will be completed. I have long executing code and also inserts so I want then to run in background. I don't want to create new Context because I don't that service had reference to data project it has reference to data.contracts project

Comment: So.  If you are going to use `Task` then you need to wait (`await`; or `Task.WaitAll()`) otherwise you run the risk of the main app exiting before the task completes.  [EF contexts are not thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455634/entity-framework-thead-safety)

Comment: @MickyD, there is `Task.WaitAll` for that

Comment: @Toolkit for what?    I already said that anyway