# .Net Entity Framework Check if value exists in different tables Optimization

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following function that checks if an Id exists in 4 different tables and returns a boolean value:

```
 public bool CheckIfUsed(int targetId)
        {
            bool isUsedOnTable1 = false;
            bool isUsedOnTable2 = false;
            bool isUsedOnTable3 = false;
            bool isUsedOnTable4 = false;

            isUsedOnTable1 = this.DbContext.table1.Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(TargetID => TargetID == targetId).Count() > 0;
            isUsedOnTable2 = this.DbContext.table2.Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(TargetID => TargetID == targetId).Count() > 0;
            isUsedOnTable3 = this.DbContext.table3.Select(target => target.TargetId).Where(targetID => targetID == targetId).Count() > 0;
            isUsedOnTable4 = this.DbContext.table4.Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(targetID => targetID == targetId).Count() > 0;

            return (isUsedOnTable1 || isUsedOnTable2 || isUsedOnTable3 || isUsedOnTable4);
        }
```

This approach technically works, the problem here is the performance issues of having 4 different queries each time this function is executed. Is there any way to check the four tables simultaneously or any other way to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the first query's result returns true, you don't have to query another tables.
In addition, you don't need count of data. That's way, It should be

```
  public async Task<bool> CheckIfUsed(int targetId)
        {
            var isUsed = false;
            isUsed = await this.DbContext.table1.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(TargetID => TargetID == targetId);
            if (isUsed)
                return isUsed;
            
            isUsed = await this.DbContext.table2.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(TargetID => TargetID == targetId);
            if (isUsed)
                return isUsed;
            
            isUsed = await this.DbContext.table3.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(TargetID => TargetID == targetId);
            if (isUsed)
                return isUsed;
            
            isUsed = await this.DbContext.table4.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(TargetID => TargetID == targetId);
            return isUsed;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u should use where first  to improve performance

```
this.DbContext.table1.Where(TargetID => TargetID == targetId).Select(target => target.TargetID).Count()
```

Because you fetch the data first, then you process it

otherway

you generat a Generic class that get Object query then get commands out of these and one huge batch [hope this helps you](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232079-multiquery-more-queries-in-one-batch-in-entity-framework-using-linq)

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries) and [`async`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-do-i-think-about-async-code/) to  disable track entities and  asynchronous execution to improve performance like this

```cs
public async Task<bool> CheckIfUsed(int targetId)
{
    Task<int> isUsedOnTable1Task = false;
    Task<int> isUsedOnTable2Task = false;
    Task<int> isUsedOnTable3Task = false;
    Task<int> isUsedOnTable4Task = false;

    bool isUsedOnTable1 = false;
    bool isUsedOnTable2 = false;
    bool isUsedOnTable3 = false;
    bool isUsedOnTable4 = false;

    isUsedOnTable1Task = this.DbContext.table1.AsNoTracking().Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(TargetID => TargetID == targetId).CountAsync();
    isUsedOnTable2Task = this.DbContext.table2.AsNoTracking().Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(TargetID => TargetID == targetId).CountAsync();
    isUsedOnTable3Task = this.DbContext.table3.AsNoTracking().Select(target => target.TargetId).Where(targetID => targetID == targetId).CountAsync();
    isUsedOnTable4Task = this.DbContext.table4.AsNoTracking().Select(target => target.TargetID).Where(targetID => targetID == targetId).CountAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(isUsedOnTable1Task, isUsedOnTable2Task, isUsedOnTable3Task, isUsedOnTable4Task)
    
    isUsedOnTable1 = isUsedOnTable1Task.Result > 0;
    isUsedOnTable2 = isUsedOnTable2Task.Result > 0;
    isUsedOnTable3 = isUsedOnTable3Task.Result > 0;
    isUsedOnTable4 = isUsedOnTable4Task.Result > 0;

    return (isUsedOnTable1 || isUsedOnTable2 || isUsedOnTable3 || isUsedOnTable4);
}
```

Remember that `EntityFramework` is not [Thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455827/7086678)