# EF Core multithreading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have a simple project which has not update/delete and I insert using dapper library. I use ef core just for fetching data (mostly asNoTracking).
Note that

- I use the default scoped DbContext
- I use a full `async` ef repository

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                
                   {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 10,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                });
            },
```

This is one of the methods in my generic repository

```cs
public async Task<List<TDto>> GetAsNoTrackingAsync<TDto>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await Context.Set<T>()
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                         .Where(predicate)
                         .OrderByDescending(e => e.RTime)
                         .ToListAsync();
        }
```

and how I use it:

```cs
var result = await _repository.GetAsNoTrackingAsync<TDto>(e => e.Id == id);
```

but unfortunately I encounter with the below multithreading issue rarely which is strange for me.

`A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.`

I have searched a lot for this issue, but found no solution except making the DbContext as transient (which I think it is not a solution).

It is not 100% percent reproduciblem but I sometimes I could do so by multiple requesting the request (e.g. clicking on F5 button twice quickly)

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the context class and a typical method that causes this exception. It's not *only* lifetime scope that can lead to this issue.

Comment: @Kourosh, Are you sure you are correctly using async await, Might be missing some await and it's executing multiple thing at same time on context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Entity Framework is not thread-safe. Each content can only be used by one thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455634/entity-framework-thread-safety

Comment: What is `services`?

Comment: @anirudhagupta Yes, I have reviewed the codes multiple times for missing `await` keyword

Comment: The problem is 2 calls are executing at the same time on same instance. If you can use some kind of lock(obj) it might help.

Comment: @gertarnold DbContext code added

Comment: @enigmativity Yes, I see. I use async/await methods fully for ef-related tasks and as my dbcontext is configured to be scoped, my question is what is the best pattern for using ef dbcontext?

Comment: @enigmativity services refers to `Startup.cs > ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method

Comment: @Kourosh - You really need to post a [mcve].